# Set time interval between two email notifications

Tags: zabbix

how can I set time interval between two email notifications that Zabbix sends? I want to send a notification about an issue at least 30 minutes since the last email about the same issue.
Currently, I get an email every minute about the same thing and that's annoying.

The only thing I found was this: https://www.zabbix.com/forum/zabbix-help/19970-time-interval-between-two-email-notifications
but unfortunately it wasn't very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can manage these intervals in `Configuration -> Actions -> your alert action -> Operations`.

I think that you have set up `Default step duration` to 1 minute and a notification action for `steps 1 - 0 (Indefinitely)`.

In the [documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.2/manual/config/notifications/action/escalations) you can find various examples, for instance:

> Example 1
>
> Sending a repeated notification once every 30 minutes (5
>   times in total) to a 'MySQL Administrators' group.
>
> To configure: 
>   in Operations tab, set the Default operation step duration to '30m'
>   (30 minutes) Set the escalation steps to be From '1' To '5' Select the
>   'MySQL Administrators' group as recipients of the message

You can define a default step duration of 1 minute and define the escalations:

- `step 1 - 1` to send a mail after 1 minute
- `step 30 - 30` to send a mail after 30 minutes
- or `step 30 - 0` to send a mail every 30 minutes